# Can Visual Studio 2017 be made to use Python shell?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017 with Visual Studio Python tools installed. All good except that when I run a Python program it will open in command prompt (or PowerShell).
I want it to open the same shell that IDLE uses.
I have tried creating a custom environment but the only relevant (to me) options are 'Interpreter Path' which is set to python.exe, and 'Windowed Interpreter' which is set to pythonw.exe, and 'Path environment variable' which is set to PYTHONPATH.
Have researched this relatively exhaustively and can't seem to find any applicable answer. 
My background is in C and asm embedded programming so trying to make a complicated IDE like Visual Studio do what I want is a bit out of my experience.

Comment: "I want it to open the same shell that IDLE uses." I'm not sure I follow, you want Visual Studio to open up IDLE and run the program in that shell?

Comment: IDLE is Python’s Integrated Development and Learning Environment (from the docs) — so what you're asking is how to run part of one IDE inside another, which is unlikely to be feasible. So if you just want an uncomplicated IDE, just use IDLE (or one of the several other free Python IDEs that exist). Also not that IDLE's "shell" is basically just the `python.exe` interpreter run without any arguments.

Comment: Guess I was thinking/hoping that the window IDLE opened was a separate small program,Unix fashion. If you're sure that it is an integral part of IDLE it would be, as you say, unlikely to be feasible. I'll leave this question open for another couple of days to see if anyone has any further thoughts. If not, I'll close it. Thanks all.